How can I make the status bar full screen without padding
I need help, I'm trying to remove the indents on the status bar and I can't figure out how to do it.
statusbar.xml from SystemUI.apk
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBarView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:systemui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.systemui"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/status_bar"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_height"
    android:accessibilityPaneTitle="@string/status_bar">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notification_lights_out"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/status_bar_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_sysbar_lights_out_dot_small"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/status_bar_padding_start"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/status_bar_contents"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/status_bar_padding_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/status_bar_padding_start"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/status_bar_padding_end">
        ... FullCode in pastebin https://pastebin.com/RrDyxhQ0 ...
    </LinearLayout>
</com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBarView>

I've already repainted the objects to try to figure out where the margins are set.
This is what it looks like
resparam.res.hookLayout("com.android.systemui", "layout", "status_bar", new XC_LayoutInflated() {
    @Override
    public void handleLayoutInflated(LayoutInflatedParam liparam) throws Throwable {
        FrameLayout status_bar = liparam.view.findViewById(
            liparam.res.getIdentifier("status_bar", "id", "com.android.systemui"));
        status_bar.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        LinearLayout status_bar_contents = liparam.view.findViewById(
                liparam.res.getIdentifier("status_bar_contents", "id", "com.android.systemui"));
        status_bar_contents.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}

I want time to start from the beginning right away frame
